# original sheet was removed when new data table writed to excel file

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

my propose:

1. if excel file not exist, create it and copy data table to it;
2. if excel file exist, copy to data table to new sheet.
   but following code running, only copy to data to new sheet, original sheet in excel file was removed.

import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

f_name = "123.xlsx"                                     #target excel file

if os.path.exists(f_name):
"""if excel file exist, added table to another sheet"""
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f_name)                      #load excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f_name, engine="openpyxl")

```
writer.wb = wb                                          
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel("table_2.xlsx"))      #get table to be added excel file
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet2",index=False)  #write to another sheet
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

else:
"""if excel file not exit, create it"""
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()                 # create excel file
df_1.to_excel(f_name)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f_name)       
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel("table_1.xlsx"))      # get table_1  
df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1",index=False)  # write table_1 into excel file  
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: should be "writer.book = wb", and not "writer.wb = wb".

Answer (score 0):

import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

f_name = "123.xlsx"                                     #target excel file

if os.path.exists(f_name):
"""if excel file exist, added table to another sheet"""
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f_name)                      #load excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f_name, engine="openpyxl")       #assign engine
writer.book = wb                                         #overwrite if no this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel("table_2.xlsx"))         #get table to be added excel file
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="table_2",index=False)    #write to another sheet
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

else:
"""if excel file not exit, create it"""
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()                 # create excel file
df_1.to_excel(f_name)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f_name)       
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel("table_1.xlsx"))      # get table_1  
df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="table_1",index=False)  # write table_1 into excel file  
writer.save()
writer.close()
```